# Server 2012 r2 hangs on different board, no event id 2019/2020

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2

I've been using this build for a while and its pretty stable.

Server 2012 r2

X99 taichi

Xeon e5 2670 ES

Corsair memory 32 gb

Intel pcie nic connected to poe switch for cctv

Kingston ssd

9202-16e hooked up to 4u60 jbod

But its rather overkill for my needs cause im just using it for emby, radarr and sonarr. And also since its connected to online ups i want it to survive long blackout since it happens often in my city.

So i looked up and built this

I7 8700

Supermicro C7z370-G-L-O

Nvme m2 samsung 970

Same memory

Same cctv nic

same sas card

In terms of power its well below my first build cause the cpu only consumes 65 watt, plus no gpu and the passmark was 50% higher iirc.

BUT its always crashing after being used for a while, and i cant figure out why, even with a brand new 9300-8e. All drivers are installed and OS is already up to date. Occasionally it would lock up and i cant do anything but force reboot it.

Upon checking event viewer, i couldnt find event 2019 / 2020 as suggested on some forums. The only related warning i could find was multiple Event ID 11 - the driver detected a controller error.

So i went back to my first machine. And the issues are gone, Since the only different component are cpu and motherboard. I'm wondering if supero board have compatibility issue with sas card..

So what else should i look in event viewer? 
Or perhaps, which z370 motherboard is fully compatible with 9202-16e / 9300-8e? Kinda dissapointed since this is my first supermicro board..

Comment: This could be so many things. I had two identical super micro boards (different from yours) hard freezing like this because there was an early firmware issue and it required coordinating with super micro, Intel, and myself to get a working update released. Make sure the board has the latest BIOS. Also perform some out of band load testing. Meaning take the OS out of the picture and run some load test boot disks, like extended memory and drive tests. Confirm RAM and CPU compatibility.

Comment: Just tested now with latest bios it's still crashing, using different ram brand that is brand new doesn't help either, i guess i'm gonna find another motherboard, seriously dissapointed with supermicro.

Comment: Could a custom intel driver be causing this? I'm using custom driver from forums because i7 8700 doesnt have official server 2012 r2 driver.

Comment: I think it is premature to blame supermicro especially if you are using a “custom” driver. I’ve never heard of loading a driver for a CPU so I’m confused. If the CPU, motherboard and OS aren’t compatible with each other then why are you trying to force it and expect it to run right?

Comment: I just installed server 2016 which has driver equivalent to windows 10, and i installed the official cpu driver but its still crashing. It has something to do with the way the board handles multiple PCIE. Fortunately the seller is willing to trade to MSI Z390. I will post the result using the new board.